# Limit private IP access only

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Is that possible to forbid the outgoing public IP address and access private IP only?

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```

I know there is a way to drop IP via `iptables`

```
iptables -I OUTPUT-s 11.0.0.0 -j DROP
... etc
```

Is there a convenient way to block all of them?

Comment: Just so I understand, you want your machine to ONLY be able to access the private IP ranges and not be able to access ANY public IPs?

Comment: @ColinWu Right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d  10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

For an accurate list of reserved address space.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but you add one more `.` in your first command

Comment: Furthermore, the private IP list is wrong. I use the following. `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, `192.168.0.0/16 `, `127.0.0.0/8`